# phpmyadmin error: the mysql extension is missing

Tags: phpmyadmin

i'm getting the following error:

phpMyAdmin - Error

```
 The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/original/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

when i try to access phpmyadmin from my IE browser: localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php

The mysql command line client is also running when im trying to access phpmyadmin.

phpmyadmin was working perfectly today morning. I tested my signup and login pages of my website and switched the computer off. Then, when I switched it back on, I got the above error. I am using some cookies in my code.

Both the pages on my website accessing the database is giving the following error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\websites\cakephp\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 613

As suggested on the net, i've already verified that I have php_mysql.dll in /php/ext folder. 
extension=php_mysql.dll is there in /php/php.ini. Extension_dir=c:/php/ext.

I have also deleted all the browsing history from internet options.

nothing seems to work. I'm clueless. Does anyone know on what i'm doing wrong?

i've installed the following: 
apache2.2, php5.3.8, phpmyadmin3.4.5, mysql5.1.59(for 64 bit), cakephp1.3.12, mongodb
separately not through WAMP or XAMP

i'm running on Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it to work. I had to reinstall everthing. And I made sure cookies are enabled in IE referring to the following link http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesie.html#ie9.

Now everthing works fine. :)